# VS Code does not recognize files in include path

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include

I am trying to do the gstreamer tutorials in C.

Unfortunately I cant even do the first one, since the includes are not working correctly.

In the tutorial code the is the include command:

`#include <gst.h>`

And when I try to run it I get the error:

`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit`

So I googled how to do it and added the include path "C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/" to my c_cpp_properties.json and my tasks.json file (even though the online answers all suggested to include "C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/include" or "C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/include/**" which did not work for me.

That seems to work at first, but when I now try to compile the project I get the error:

`In file included from basic-tutorial-1.c:2:0: C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:29:29: fatal error: gst/glib-compat.h: No such file or directory #include <gst/glib-compat.h>`

even though glib-compat.h exists in the same path as gst.h and the include path apparently is correctly recognized.

I dont use advanced setting in VS Code often and find it a bit complicated, but I assume I am not supposed to include every single header file individually.

Does someone maybe know what is the problem?

My current compile command is `gcc -c basic-tutorial-1.c -I"C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst" -I"C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/include/glib-2.0" -I"C:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/lib/glib-2.0/include"`

I know one would assume that problem is solved online a thousand times, but I cant find the solution that works for me.

Tried to include different paths and subdirectories.

Expected to compile/build without errors.

Comment: + many more on StackOverflow.

Comment: Why not read a question first before marking it as a duplicate and refer to another question that I specifically said was not the solution to my problem.

Comment: It is - you need to add the paths where your include files are.

Comment: I already did that. gst.h and glib-compat.h are in the same path. It does find gst.h. It does not find glib-compat.h. The refered answer does not adress this problem.